# Android - SimpleCursorTreeAdapter - bindChildView override

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

how to customize row layout depending on cursor specific value? Guess I need to customize bindChildView - but how? :)

Main function:

```
public void fillQuestions(int id) {
        Cursor questionsCursor = db.getQuestions(id);
        EventActivity.this.startManagingCursor(questionsCursor);
        questionsCursor.moveToFirst();

        ExpandableListView questionsList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv_questions);

        ExpandableQuestionsAdapter adapter = new ExpandableQuestionsAdapter(
                questionsCursor,
                EventActivity.this,
                R.layout.display_name_row,
                R.layout.display_cb_answer_row,
                new String[] {"questionText"},
                new int[] {R.id.r_lv_name},
                new String[] {"answerName"},
                new int[] {R.id.r_lv_cb_name});



    }
```

Adapter:

```
    public class ExpandableQuestionsAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {


            public ExpandableQuestionsAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context, int groupLayout,
                                              int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom,
                                              int[] childrenTo) {
                super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
            }

            @Override
            protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
                Cursor childCursor = db.getAnswers(groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_F_ID)));
                EventActivity.this.startManagingCursor(childCursor);
                childCursor.moveToFirst();
                return childCursor;

            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View rowView = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
                return rowView;
            }

            @Override
            protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
                super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);
            }
        }
```

I tried to look for some examples, unfortunately couldn't;t find any - any help appreciated

Thanks,
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

i am not big proffecional but maybe my research can help you

```
protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor getChildrenCursor, boolean isLastChild) {
        super.bindChildView(view, context, getChildrenCursor, isLastChild);
        //take value from getChildrenCursor but its also work with just cursor, because its already have correct position
        String color = getChildrenCursor.getString(getChildrenCursor.getColumnIndex(COLOR));
        //String color ="#1B3F51B5";
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
```

in my case i have specific column COLOR that have color value like #1B3F51B5
also instead of view.setBackgroundColor you can use something like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.r_lv_name);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```